# Implement 'Bowtie' type text in svg

Tags: html, svg

Is there any way to implement 'Bowtie' type text using svg? I know how to do it in canvas but implementing it in svg is becoming a challenge.

An image to give you more idea about the text:

[image]

Comment: Not really, SVG does not support non-affine transforms. You could try breaking up the text and doing 2 CSS 3d transforms but you can't do the W that way.

Comment: You could try a library like https://github.com/benjamminf/warpjs

Comment: If you add a bigger resolution image, I can do it for you